# Knockout JS binding "options" is not changing the whole object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have following code:

**models.js**

```
class MyModel {
    constructor(value, title) {
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
        this.title = ko.observable(title);
    }
}

class MyWrapper {
    constructor(selected_model) {
        this.selected_model = ko.observable(selected_model);
    }
}
```

**view_model.js**

```
class MyVM {
    constructor() {
        let items = [
            new MyModel(1, 'One'),
            new MyModel(2, 'Two'),
            new MyModel(3, 'Three')
        ];

        this.object_to_work_with = ko.observable(new MyWrapper(items[1]));
        this.my_list = ko.observableArray(items);
    }
}
```

**html template**

```
<div data-bind="with: object_to_work_with">
    <select id="my_list" data-bind="options: $root.my_list,
                                    optionsValue: 'value',
                                    optionsText: 'title'
                                    value: selected_model().value"></select>
</div>
```

And now the issue. At first I thought the value should be `selected_model` directly:

```
<div data-bind="with: object_to_work_with">
    <select id="my_list" data-bind="options: $root.my_list,
                                    optionsValue: 'value',
                                    optionsText: 'title'
                                    value: selected_model"></select>
</div>
```

but this do not work, it causes an error like "undefined has no property 'value'". So I've tried `value: selected_model()`, now it worked and correct value was selected, but as literal -> if I changed it, `object_to_work_with.selected_model()` is not changed. And the last try was `value: selected_model().value` and it seemed to work, but now when I select another value, it does not change `object_to_work_with.selected_model()`, it changes only the value of selected model, I mean this `object_to_work_with.selected_model().value() => <the value I've selected>`, but `object_to_work_with.selected_model().title() => 'Two'` is never changed.

I am searching a solution quite long time and I have no idea how to solve it. According to the [manual](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) it looks like it should be `value: selected_model`, but it causes the exception and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Any idea please?

Edit:
And moreover the last option `value: selected_model().value` is changing the value of the item in `my_list`, because it is of course only reference.

Edit 2:
Here I've created a working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/L7tsy4ae/. Just try to use selectbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go with the `optionsValue: 'value'` binding, you also have to initialize the `selected_model` with `items[1].value`. Instead, I'd opt for not using the `optionsValue` binding at all so your selection can point to the actual viewmodel.

Here's a working example (with some other other changes not strictly needed: removed the observable wrapper of `object_to_work_with` and replaced the `change` event binding with a `subscribe` inside the viewmodel.)

```js
class MyModel {
    constructor(value, title) {
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
        this.title = ko.observable(title);
    }
}

class MyWrapper {
    constructor(selected_model) {
        this.selected_model = ko.observable(selected_model);
    }
}

class MyVM {
    constructor() {
        let items = [
            new MyModel(1, 'One'),
            new MyModel(2, 'Two'),
            new MyModel(3, 'Three')
        ];

        this.object_to_work_with = new MyWrapper(items[1]);
        this.my_list = ko.observableArray(items);
        
        this.object_to_work_with.selected_model.subscribe(this.print_data, this);
    }
    
    print_data(selected_model) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const text = document.createTextNode(
            `${selected_model.title()}: ${selected_model.value()}`
        );
        
        div.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('data').appendChild(div);
    }
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new MyVM());
```

```css
#content {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#data {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="content" data-bind="with: object_to_work_with">
    <select id="my_list" data-bind="options: $root.my_list,
                                    optionsText: 'title',
                                    value: selected_model"></select>
    <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, you are really awesome. It is working as a charm. I've just removed `optionsValue: 'value',` and that's it! Thank you. I'll look at `subscribe`, I am not familiar with `subscribe` but I need to make something when the value is changed. And `object_to_work_with` is some observable object in the system and it is necessary to be an observable because the system is working with this variable in many ways. But again, thank you :-).

Comment: Ah, I kind of expected you put that inside another observable for a reason... In that case the subscribe gets a little bit trickier. But I'm sure you'll figure it out! If not, you can always ask another question on stack overflow 

Comment: One more question @user3297291, please. Could you please explain me why the `object` in the method `print_data(object, event)` is `object_to_work_with` and not `selected_model` when I use change event? I need data of selected model and I have to call `object_to_work_with.selected_model` instead of `selected_model` only. And it is even worse in my real application - I have to go through `ko.contextFor(event.target).$root.some_of_my_view_models.selected_model`. So, why change event sends the wrapper instead of the object which was changed? Thank you

Comment: Knockout passes the current `$data` from the binding context. You might want to try to wrap the `<select>` inside a `with: selected_model`, and then use `value: value`.

Comment: Thank you again. Your advice was a solution, but I had to use `$data` as the value. Thank you very much.